# Cannot read property 'toString' of null -- Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I create in a component (active.ts) a function that activate a product. In active.html i create a slide-toggle form. This component I want to used in anther component to see and used from that.

```
export class Product { 
    product_id: string; 
    active: number; 
    public gup(token: string, id?: number): string { 
        let usp = new URLSearchParams(); 
        usp.append('active', this.active.toString()); 
        usp.append('product_id', this.product_id.toString()); 
        usp.append('token', token); 
        return usp.toString(); 
    } 
}
```

My code active.ts

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'sdci-active-form',
  templateUrl: './sdci-active-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sdci-active-form.component.css']
})

    export class Active implements OnInit {
          activate: FormGroup;
          prod: Product;
          loading: boolean = false;
          device: number = 1;
          constructor(private ws: serviceh,
            private router: Router,
            private fb: FormBuilder,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
          ) {

            this.activate = this.fb.group({
              'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
            });
          } 
          ngOnInit() {  
            this.activeform();
          }
          activeform() {
            this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
              params => {
                this.ws.getproductById(params['id']).subscribe(
                  prod => {
                    this.prod = prod;
                    this.activate.controls['active'].setValue(prod.active);
                  }
                );
              }
            );
          }
          onActiveProduct() {
            this.loading = true;
            let editprod = new Product(
              this.activate.value
            );
            editprod.product_id = this.prod.product_id;
            this.ws.activateprod(editprod).subscribe(
              result => {
                if (result === true) {
                return true
                } else {
                  this.loading = false;
                }
              },
              error => {
                this.loading = false;
              }
            );
          }
          onChange(value) {
            if (value.checked === true) {
              this.device = 1;
            } else {
              this.device = 0;
            }
          }
        }
```

active html

```
<form [formGroup]="activeform" class="col s12" materialize>
<mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" id="active" [(ngModel)]="device" (change)="onChange($event)" (click)="onActiveProduct()">
</mat-slide-toggle>
{{device}}
</form>
```

And this, I want ot acess form another component.

Product.html

```
 <sdci-active-form(click)="onActiveProduct($event)"></sdci-active-form>
```

This dosen't function because Cannot read property 'toString' of null

I think also, because don't know product_id, when I use from component active, this work good. In another component doesn't work.

Can you suggest me any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I can not see `toString ` in your code anywhere.

Comment: export class Product {  product_id: string;  active: number;    public gup(token: string, id?: number): string {
        let usp = new URLSearchParams();
        usp.append('active', this.active.toString());
        usp.append('product_id', this.product_id.toString());
        usp.append('token', token);
        return usp.toString();
    }
}

Comment: Since `product_id` is a string, you can replace `this.product_id.toString()` with `this.product_id` in the `gup` method.